# How to make an android app which determines location and finds nearest

Tags: android

I am creating an app for android which will be used by gym members. I need to find a tutorial or any other material which may help me to give the user an option to "find nearest gym". This will determine the location of the user and display their closest gym options to their location.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Google Places API has a gym category:
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/supported_types.html

A tutorial for using the API is here:
http://blog.brianbuikema.com/2010/08/android-development-part-1-using-googles-places-api-to-develop-compelling-location-based-mobile-applications/